# VBA: Userform Error date values change - months as days and days as months

Tags: vba, excel, userform, date-formatting

I'm using this [calendar](https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class) in my userform to enter dates in Textbox1. It works fine within the userform (format "dd/mm/yyyy") - no problem either filling dates directly to an active cell.

The problem comes when passing the data from the userform to the worksheet. The date format stays "dd/mm/yyyy" but Changing the day value as month and month as day ( March 1 becomes january 3).

```
ws.Cells(MyNR, 1) = tbFi.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 2) = tbNh.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 3) = tbTh.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 4) = cbN1.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 5) = cbPoc.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 6) = cbNa1.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 7) = cbPoca1.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 8) = cbNa2.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 9) = cbPoca2.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 10) = cbNa3.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 11) = cbPoca3.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 12) = cbNa4.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 13) = cbPoca4.Value
ws.Cells(MyNR, 14) = TextBox1.value
   'ws.Cells(mynr, 14).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" not working
ws.Cells(MyNR, 15) = TextBox2.value
    'ws.Cells(mynr, 15).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
ws.Cells(MyNR, 16) = cbQac.Value
```

Comment: Does this occur to all cells or only those in columns `N, O`?

Comment: Generally formatting is best done in the sheet I believe with dates. You could try ws.Cells(MyNR, 14) = Format$(TextBox1.value,"dd/mm/yyyy")? The unambiguous date format to use is yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Those are the only columns containing dates. Changed it so it saves the data in other columns and the same happens.

Comment: Have you formatted the columns with the desired date format?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that it also changes the month value as day and day as month, so it doesn't matter with format I chose.

Comment: @DiegoAli Did you try `ws.Cells(MyNR, 14) = CDate(TextBox1.Value)`?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, it didn't actually change the format it took the day values as month and vice versa.

Comment: ws.Cells(MyNR, 14) = CDate(TextBox1.Value) worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CDate` to convert the text to a real date value:

```
ws.Cells(MyNR, 14).Value = CDate(TextBox1.value)
ws.Cells(MyNR, 15).Value = CDate(TextBox2.value)
```

Comment: I find CDate can also still output US format at times unless what goes in is unambiguous as yyyy-mm-dd. Or have I got that wrong?

Comment: @QHarr CDate uses your regional settings. Unless you have those set to US format, I have never seen it do what you describe.

Comment: Ah.. it is entirely possible my IT dept has it set as US. We get frequent installs that don't always align.

Comment: #note2selfadded